# postfix notation program in C, didn't get the expected output

Tags: c

The program is a simple calculator that reads input from the keyboard in the
postfix notation and performs calculation for integer numbers
can someone help me find the problem in my code?
here are the codes:
main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "calc.h" /* header file */

#define MAXOP 128

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF) {
        switch(type) {
        case NUMBER:
            push(atoi(s));
            break;  
        case '+':
            push(pop() + pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
            break;
        case '*':
            push(pop() * pop());
            break;
        case '/':
            op2 = pop();
            if (op2 != 0.0)
                push(pop() / op2);
            else {
                printf("error : zero divisor\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            break;
    case '&':
        push(pop() & pop());
        break;
    case '|':
        push(pop() | pop());
    case '^':
        push(pop() ^ pop());
        break;
    case '~':
        push(~pop());
        break;
    case '>':
        push(pop() > pop());
        break;
    case '=':
        push(pop() == pop());
        break;
    case '<':
        push(pop() < pop());
        break;
    //return 1 if number is 0 otherwise 1
    case '!':
        push(!pop());
        break;
    case '?':
        if(pop() > 0)
        push(pop());
        break; 
        case '\n':
            printf("The answer is %d.\n", pop());
            break;
        default:
            printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
            exit(1);
          
        }
    }
}
```

stack.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "calc.h"

#define MAXVAL 1024  /* maximum depth of val stack */

static int val[MAXVAL];    /* value stack */
static unsigned stackTop = 0; /* next free stack position */

/* push: push i onto value stack */
void push(int i) {
    /* If the stack has free position, store the value */
    if (stackTop < MAXVAL) {
        val[stackTop++] = i;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: stack full, can't push %d\n", i);
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* pop: pop and return top value from stack */
int pop(void) {
    /* If the stack contains values, return the last one */
    if (stackTop != 0) {
    int x = val[--stackTop];
    return x;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: stack empty\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

clac.h:

```
#define NUMBER '0'

/* stack.c */
void push(int);
int pop(void);

/* getop.c */
int getop(char[]);

/* getch.c */
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);
```

getch.c

```
*
 * getch.c
 *
 * getch returns one character from stdin 
 * or from the buffer buf if it is not empty
 * ungetch puts one character in the buffer buf 
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

static char buf[BUFSIZE] ;  /* buffer for ungetch */
static unsigned bufTop = 0; /* next free position in buf */

/* get a (possibly pushed back) character */
int getch(void) {
    return (bufTop > 0) ? buf[--bufTop] : getchar();
}

/* push character back on input */
void ungetch(int c) {
    if (bufTop >= BUFSIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ungetch: buffer full\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        buf[bufTop++] = c;
}
```

getop.c

```
/* 
 * getop.c
 *
 * Gets next token: operator or numeric operand
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "calc.h"

int getop(char s[]) {
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;

    s[1] = '\0';

    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c;  /* not a number */

    /* collect integer part in string s */
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c))
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;

    /* collect fractional part in string s */
    if (c == '.')
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    
    return NUMBER;
}
```

makefile

```
# Makefile for project 1
# format of entries;

# <target list>: <dependency list>
#   <command list>

# make will look at the last-write dates of each file, and if the
# target file hasn't been updated since the source files were last
# modified, it will update the target file by executing the shell
# command.  Note that the character before <command list> MUST be a
# tab, not spaces.


calc: main.o getop.o stack.o getch.o        
    gcc -o calc main.o getop.o stack.o getch.o

# note that if calc.h changes, main.c and getop.c must be recompiled

main.o: main.c calc.h
    gcc -c main.c   

getop.o: getop.c calc.h
    gcc -c getop.c

stack.o: stack.c  
    gcc -c stack.c

getch.o: getch.c
    gcc -c getch.c

# This tells make what to make if you just type 'make'; if this isn't
# there, the first rule in the file will be the default.

# .DEFAULT_GOAL := calc

# Here is a rule to clean up the directory when calc is final and you
# want to reduce the clutter in the listing.  Note that clean doesn't
# need to depend on any file modification time, so the <dependency
# list> position is just left empty.

clean:
    rm *.o
```

testPostfix.txt

```
65535 255 &
1024 255 |
255 255 ^
32767 ~
123 456 >
123 456 =
123 456 <
0 !
5 !
2 3 0 ?
2 3 11 ?
2 99 + 65535 1024 & 2048 1024 | 255 254 ^ ? 4 5 > ?
```

the expected outputs are:
[image]

but when I execute my program, I got this output

[image]

Comment: This problem statement is misleading..  It implies that you should implement the whole program before testing it.  That is NOT a good approach, especially when a beginner like yourself does so and is immediately lost when it "doesn't work".  You need to step through your program's execution in a debugger or otherwise output information about its internal state to isolate which parts work as expected and which parts don't.  Programming and debugging go hand in hand.  You really cannot be a programmer without knowing how to troubleshoot.

Comment: A quick skim-read of your program shows that `case '|'` does not have a `break`, whereas all the other operators do.  That looks like a mistake, as it wouldn't make sense for it to fall-through to the `'^'` operator.  I would start by fixing that.  Obviously, if you set a breakpoint on your "stack is empty" error, then you would be able to see the callstack at that point.  I'd expect it probably happens there.  Maybe there's other issues.